# how to handle unique identifier parameter in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to delete a row from gridview and database based on it's id which is unique identifier.
In my code below I get error msg " Unrecognized Guid format" .Any help to fix it?

```
         protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

       string id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Delete", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
         command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = new System.Guid(id); 
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(ds);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        command.Connection.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Guid theGuid = new Guid();
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid.Parse(theGuid.ToString());
```

[Adding a Guid Parameter into SqlCommand](http://weblogs.asp.net/thiagosantos/archive/2009/01/13/adding-a-guid-parameter-into-sqlcommand.aspx)

Comment: string id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
            Guid myid = new Guid(id);
            System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid theSqlGuid = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid(myid);

Answer (score 0):

Use [Guid.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) on your id string, then you'll know what's going on.

Comment: I still get the same error after using guid.tryparse like  string id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
            Guid myid ;Guid.TryParse(id, out myid);